# jquery delay between javascript functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

I have multiply functions with parameters simplified as:

```
    function f1(p1,p2){
        alert('Function one is P1:'+p1+' P2:'+p2);        
    }
    function f2(p1,p2){
        alert('Function two is P1:'+p1+' P2:'+p2);
    }
```

I need to fire these is a sequence with a delay between. I have however found that jQuery dislikes running functions with parameters. I have tried the .click function.

```
$.delay(1000).click(f1('One',false)).delay(1000).click(f2('One',false));
```

But the delay makes the click functions not work...

Comment: Agreed - no need for jQuery at all here. Not sure what the `click` connection is.

Comment: jQuery's [`queue`](http://api.jquery.com/queue) method is relevant for performing actions on DOM nodes between animations and the like.

Comment: `$.delay` is not a valid method unless you're using a plugin that you haven't told us about.

Comment: I just don't understand how `.click` was a possible solution to this problem.

Comment: thanks for all the answers, my problem is however that I have 7 functions all needing to be executed with a delay, some of them a jquery some a normal and some are both...

Comment: jQuery delay() can only be used in regards to jQuery queues/animations. Unfortunately, delay() can't apply to just any function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would just use a simple timeout:

```
f1("one", false);
setTimeout(function() { f2("one", false); }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.delay(1000).click(function(){f1('One',false);}).delay(1000).click(function(){f2('One',false);});
```

not sure what the click is for though ...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to delay a function call then a much simpler way is to use setTimeout().

eg:
// calling it in a nested setTimeout for sequential delayed execution 
    setTimeout(function(){

```
 f1('One',false);
  setTimeout(function(){
    f1('One',false)
  },300)
},300)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function fn1()
{
    alert(1);
}
function fn2()
{
    alert(2);
}
var arr=[fn1,fn2];
var len=arr.length;
var time=1000;
for(var k=0;k<len;k++)
{
    (function(k)
    {
        setTimeout(arr[k],time);
    }(k))
    time=time*2;
}
```

It executes after a delay of 1 second!
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mtvY9/)